# Parsing Through EC2 Tags for specific value

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sorting, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am trying to pull some tags through my AWS SDK Java application and I am able to retrieve all of the tags but I am having trouble parsing through all of the keys to get the specific value that I want.

I am specifically looking for the 'Name' key and the value that is associated with that key. When I call the API, it returns a List so I am able to parse through the list but each Tag has multiple Keys that aren't indexable so I am struggling to get the key desired.

Here is what the response looks like

```
[Tag(Key=Name, Value=Test)]
[Tag(Key=elasticbeanstalk:environment-id, Value=XXX), Tag(Key=aws:cloudformation:stack-id, Value=XXX), Tag(Key=aws:autoscaling:groupName, Value=XXX), Tag(Key=aws:cloudformation:stack-name, Value=XXX), Tag(Key=aws:cloudformation:logical-id, Value=XXX), Tag(Key=elasticbeanstalk:environment-name, Value=XXX), Tag(Key=Name, Value=TestJar-env)]
[Tag(Key=Name, Value=Test1)]
```

As you can see, sometimes the key "name" is the only one in the tag so it is easy to pull it out, but if there are multiple, that is when the challenge arrises.

**Edit**

Here is the code that I am using to get the response posted above

```
for (int i = 0; i < instance.tags().size() ; i++) {
    System.out.println(instance.tags().get(i));
}
```

Comment: please add the code that you are using

Comment: Presumably you have a Collection or List or array of com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.Tag objects. A simple solution is to iterate over the collection and find the first item that has a Key of "Name".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to iterate through the tags to find whether or not the tags had the key value of "Name". If they did, I took that and paired it with the value. The problem was the response that I was reading. I thought the entire response above was the List where in reality, the response above was printing out the lists of tags that could be iterated through.

```
for (int i = 0; i < instance.tags().size() ; i++) {
    if (instance.tags().get(i).key().equals("Name")){
        instanceArrayListTagName.add(instance.tags().get(i).value());
    }
}
```